# MultiSelectListPreferenceDialogFragment cannot be shown with SupportFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

When using MultiSelectListPreference with PreferenceFragmentCompat, like all preference with dialogs, we need to use a DialogFragment to show the preference interface and capture the input.  The support library provides just such a dialog fragment: MultiSelectListPreferenceDialogFragment

However, this inherits from android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceDialogFragment which inherits from android.app.DialogFragment.  In other words, it cannot be shown with the SupportFragmentManager, effectively making it impossible to use the MultiSelectList preference if your app is designed around the support libraries.

Luckily, there is no reason I could find for this, so a workaround is to just copy'n'paste the google code from MultiSelectListPreferenceDialogFragment and PreferenceDialogFragment and change the inheritance to extend android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.

I filed a bug with google ([here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207096)) and the code is below.  I was using com.android.support:preference-v14:23.3.0

This works fine for my project, but I don't understand the logic behind limiting the use of these support preferences to non-support centric apps.  I understand it is in the v14 support library, but other support libraries require the SupportFragmentManager, etc. and all the docs recommend using the support libraries.  Is there a better way to go about this?

**MultiSelectPrefenceDialog (replaces MultiSelectListPreferenceDialogFragment)**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License
 */

public class MultiSelectPreferenceDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    private Set<String> mNewValues = new HashSet<>();
    private boolean mPreferenceChanged;

    protected static final String ARG_KEY = "key";
    private DialogPreference mPreference;

    /** Which button was clicked. */
    private int mWhichButtonClicked;

    public static MultiSelectPreferenceDialog newInstance(String key) {
            final MultiSelectPreferenceDialog fragment =
                    new MultiSelectPreferenceDialog();
            final Bundle b = new Bundle(1);
            b.putString(ARG_KEY, key);
            fragment.setArguments(b);
            return fragment;
        }

        private MultiSelectListPreference getListPreference() {
            return (MultiSelectListPreference) getPreference();
        }

        protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
            final MultiSelectListPreference preference = getListPreference();
            if (preference.getEntries() == null || preference.getEntryValues() == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "MultiSelectListPreference requires an entries array and " +
                                "an entryValues array.");
            }

            boolean[] checkedItems = getSelectedItems(preference);
            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(preference.getEntries(), checkedItems,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                mPreferenceChanged |= mNewValues.add(
                                        preference.getEntryValues()[which].toString());
                            } else {
                                mPreferenceChanged |= mNewValues.remove(
                                        preference.getEntryValues()[which].toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
            mNewValues.clear();
            mNewValues.addAll(preference.getValues());
        }

        public void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
            final MultiSelectListPreference preference = getListPreference();
            if (positiveResult && mPreferenceChanged) {
                final Set<String> values = mNewValues;
                if (preference.callChangeListener(values)) {
                    preference.setValues(values);
                }
            }
            mPreferenceChanged = false;
        }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Fragment rawFragment = getTargetFragment();
        if (!(rawFragment instanceof DialogPreference.TargetFragment)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Target fragment must implement TargetFragment" +
                    " interface");
        }
        final DialogPreference.TargetFragment fragment =
                (DialogPreference.TargetFragment) rawFragment;
        final String key = getArguments().getString(ARG_KEY);
        mPreference = (DialogPreference) fragment.findPreference(key);
    }
    @Override
    public @NonNull
    Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = getActivity();
        mWhichButtonClicked = DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE;
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(mPreference.getDialogTitle())
                .setIcon(mPreference.getDialogIcon())
                .setPositiveButton(mPreference.getPositiveButtonText(), this)
                .setNegativeButton(mPreference.getNegativeButtonText(), this);
        View contentView = onCreateDialogView(context);
        if (contentView != null) {
            onBindDialogView(contentView);
            builder.setView(contentView);
        } else {
            builder.setMessage(mPreference.getDialogMessage());
        }
        onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
        // Create the dialog
        final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        if (needInputMethod()) {
            requestInputMethod(dialog);
        }
        return builder.create();
    }
    /**
     * Get the preference that requested this dialog. Available after {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} has
     * been called.
     *
     * @return The {@link DialogPreference} associated with this
     * dialog.
     */
    public DialogPreference getPreference() {
        return mPreference;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the preference needs to display a soft input method when the dialog
     * is displayed. Default is false. Subclasses should override this method if they need
     * the soft input method brought up automatically.
     * @hide
     */
    protected boolean needInputMethod() {
        return false;
    }
    /**
     * Sets the required flags on the dialog window to enable input method window to show up.
     */
    private void requestInputMethod(Dialog dialog) {
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
    /**
     * Creates the content view for the dialog (if a custom content view is
     * required). By default, it inflates the dialog layout resource if it is
     * set.
     *
     * @return The content View for the dialog.
     * @see DialogPreference#setLayoutResource(int)
     */
    protected View onCreateDialogView(Context context) {
        final int resId = mPreference.getDialogLayoutResource();
        if (resId == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    }
    /**
     * Binds views in the content View of the dialog to data.
     * <p>
     * Make sure to call through to the superclass implementation.
     *
     * @param view The content View of the dialog, if it is custom.
     */
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        View dialogMessageView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if (dialogMessageView != null) {
            final CharSequence message = mPreference.getDialogMessage();
            int newVisibility = View.GONE;
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                if (dialogMessageView instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) dialogMessageView).setText(message);
                }
                newVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
            }
            if (dialogMessageView.getVisibility() != newVisibility) {
                dialogMessageView.setVisibility(newVisibility);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        mWhichButtonClicked = which;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        onDialogClosed(mWhichButtonClicked == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    }

    public boolean[] getSelectedItems(MultiSelectListPreference preference) {
        final CharSequence[] entries = preference.getEntryValues();
        final int entryCount = entries.length;
        final Set<String> values = preference.getValues();
        boolean[] result = new boolean[entryCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < entryCount; i++) {
            result[i] = values.contains(entries[i].toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Calling dialog fragment in PreferenceFragmentCompat**

```
@Override
public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
if (preference instanceof MultiSelectListPreference) {
        MultiSelectPreferenceDialog multi_fragment = MultiSelectPreferenceDialog.newInstance(preference.getKey());
        multi_fragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        multi_fragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"MULTISELECT_PREFERENCE_DIALOG");
    } else
        super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
}
```